# Trouble with Windows 10 + Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

Basically I've been using windows 10 on my hard disk (this is a laptop) and booting in kali linux with a usb stick from time to time, but since I realized I liked Linux a lot I decided to try a dual boot with Ubuntu (I have a backup just in case) possibly without wiping my data. So I made a live USB, booted into it and selected the 'install' option that appears on the desktop. I went with the 'dual boot with windows 10' option. I'm writing from Ubuntu from my main hard disk right now, but the problem is that from what I understood when I boot the 'black menu' (I think it's the grub bootloader or something like that) I should see an option to boot from windows, but I only have three options: Ubuntu, Advanced Ubuntu Settings (or something like that) and finally 'setup system' (once again, something like that). No Windows 10 option! As soon as I noticed it I installed GPARTED (I made some experience with kali) and I saw that windows is still there (could have done it with nautilus but due to being used to the crappy explorer in windows which can't even see freaking partitions I didn't think about it), so now if I'll have to reinstall Windows I can pass my old files which are still there with no problem (even though I'd prefer to resolve this with some faster solution), but even then, how can I keep both without ubuntu doing this? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: Fixed it! As @oldfred suggested I ran `sudo update-grub` and everything worked from then on.

Comment: If newer system that originally came with Windows 10 then it is UEFI. First run 'sudo update-grub` if you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but make sure Windows fast start up is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions If installed in BIOS boot mode to gpt drive, Boot-Repair can convert using advanced mode and total reinstall of grub2 to get UEFI version. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred This laptop came with windows 8, plus in the installation process they told me something about uefi and how installing ubuntu as uefi would prevent me from booting windows and I clicked on 'back' so it shouldn't be uefi.

Comment: The thing is it should have been installed in UEFI mode so please follow the above instructions.

Comment: @oldfred HOLY CRAP SUDO UPDATE GRUB WORKED!!!! Thank you!

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Installing Windows or any other operating system wouldn't remove Ubuntu unless you chose the Ubuntu partition for your install, and formatted the partition.  Since you say you see Windows with GParted, then you know which partition to install Windows.  You also can see which partitions have any of your other Operating systems.

Installing Windows would most wipe out Grub.  So after you install Windows you will have to reinstall grub.  This is easily done from the LiveUSB or LiveDVD disk and running the steps provided [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/877815/29012).

Comment: I installed ubuntu after, not viceversa

Comment: My answer was a response to the part of your question about what would happen if you reinstalled Windows.  I was explaining to you that nothing will happen to the actually Ubuntu.  Only grub.  If you reinstall Windows, it will overwrite Grub.

Comment: oh ok I didn't understand it sorry

Answer (score 0):

sudo update-grub solved the problem.

Comment: **To close voters:** This answer merely repeats the "answer" at the bottom of the question body. Since OP didn't bother to post an answer I'd prefer to leave this one.