# Windows 10 doesnt boot off external after Ubuntu Install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have two drives, 1tb SSD with windows 10 installed and another 64tb SSD where Ubuntu was installed.  During the installation process (because Im so smart) I selected erase windows and install Ubuntu instead of selecting install alongside, thinking that because theyre separate SSDs that would just reformat the 64tb to ext4 and install Ubuntu. Well Ubuntu was installed on the 64tb SSD no problem but now the Windows 10 installation doesnt boot or show up.

All the windows files are still there and the data hasn't been touched, except when I tried(and failed) to fix the problem with Boot-Repair.  How do I get the windows to boot up again?

Boot Repair Link
http://paste2.org/GE9z6NBX

Comment: Boot-Repair gives a link that you can share with the community that is helping you.  Will add that link to your question?

Comment: @L.D.James Done

Comment: Reinstall Grub using the steps provided in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/877815/29012).  Since you are using **Legacy** mode, skiop steps #3 and #9.  Use `/dev/sda` for step #1.  Use `/sda` for step #5.  When you boot, choose your 1 hard drive for the boot device  (`/dev/sda`).

Comment: @L.D.James Went through the steps provide to no avail. Ran boot repair to get a summary http://paste2.org/gVFJkGGe

Comment: Did any of the steps give any errors?

Comment: @L.D.James Negative, I'm not that lucky.