# Can't boot windows after installing over Ubuntu - I just get the GRUB command line

Tags: grub2, windows-10

I tried installing windows 10 enterprise over Ubuntu 14. the installation process went fine but after restarting my
laptop now it just shows

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02-beta2-9ubuntu1 minimal BASH-like line editing is supported
```

Answer (score 1):

Boot to a LiveUSB and `fsck` on the root partition of your Ubuntu installation.

You can check the partitions by examining the `/etc/fstab` file.

```
$ sudo blkid
```

Run this command, replacing `sdXY` with the partition found from the command above.

```
$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sdXY
```

**After the check performs without errors, reboot as normal.**

The above will ensure the integrity of your OS partition.  Additionally, and very common, you **may have to reinstall Grub** using the steps provided in this answer: [Installing Windows 10 on partition removed Ubuntu option](https://askubuntu.com/a/877815/29012)