# Windows 10 cannot boot after installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

im having a serious problem after installing ubuntu 16, the problem is that before ubuntu i was having a windows 10 OS and i wanted to make it dual boot so i installed ubuntu, but now the windows os is not booting, i tried many things, i disable bios secure boot, i install bootrepair and do the recommended fix but nothing. i generate a logs from bootrepair please help me because i don't know what to do and i forget to take a backup of windows os so i don't want to do a fresh install of windows, i will loose many things

Here is the pastebin logs

Before bootrepair: http://paste2.org/0N8twd1t

After bootrepair: http://paste2.org/d88kD1EM

also i tried to fix it with windows system repair but isn't work

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by reinstalling and updating Grub.

**Be sure to boot in UEFI mode.**  You can verify this after you have booted to the liveUSB by running this command:

```
$ dmesg | egrep "EFI v"
```

If you have booted **UEFI** you will see the version as the output (example: `EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends`).  If you are in Legacy the output will be empty.

Follow the steps in this Answer:
[Installing Windows 10 on partition removed Ubuntu option for UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/a/877815/29012)

From your pastebin information, use these arguments for the steps:

```
/dev/sdX# = /dev/sda9  (This is your Ubuntu installed partiton)
/dev/sdY# = /dev/sda2  (This is your EFI parition)
/dev/sdZ=   /dev/sda   (This is the drive that you will boot to set via your BIOS)
```

After performing the steps, all your recognized OS's will be added to the Grub menu.

I understand you said you had problems when trying to repair by using Windows Boot repair utility.  It's my experience that Grub is more robust for booting the various OSes that are detected as installed.

Comment: is it possible to remove Ubuntu and  recover the windows os as it was before installing ubuntu?

Comment: It's possible.  That would involve using Windows instead of using Ubuntu.  You can get support for using Windows and windows tools at http://superuser.com.