# Downloaded Ubuntu for dual boot with windows 10 but not in grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Hey guys I downloaded Ubuntu following a you tube tutorial to dual boot and put it on separate partition and when I do boot it, it only gives me option to boot into Ubuntu -  I've also changed boot priorities and it still boots into Ubuntu, now I think i have messed something up for sure. I have tried updating via terminal, still nothing. Any help would be appreciated highly :) ?

I can also access files from the harddrive windows 10 is on so that also is a good thing lol just wont let me boot into windows 10 :(

FOR  L. D. James :)... ... and other's.

```
NAME   MOUNTPOINT LABEL   SIZE FSTYPE UUID
sdb                     931.5G        
├─sdb2                      1K        
├─sdb5 /                912.4G ext4   bace354f-e906-4755-ad6b-e3b656b82b2e
└─sdb1 [SWAP]            19.1G swap   8538af63-57e4-42c6-aeb0-0356eb6afc76
sr0                      1024M        
sda                       2.7T        
├─sda2                    450M ntfs   CCD66DCED66DB97A
└─sda1                    1.8T ntfs   EA1E52601E5225BB
sr1                      1024M        
Model: ATA WDC WD30EZRX-22D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1989GB  1989GB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      2199GB  2199GB  472MB   primary  ntfs         diag


Model: ATA ST1000DM003-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  20.5GB  20.5GB  primary   linux-swap(v1)  boot
 2      20.5GB  1000GB  980GB   extended
 5      20.5GB  1000GB  980GB   logical   ext4



ngolokante7@Humza:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-22-generic
done
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update your GRUB boot-manager to add Windows 10 to your Grub menu.

The command to update GRUB is:
*(In the commands you see a `$` prompt.  That is the prompt you see on the terminal.  It's showing that the commands are typed from a normal user logon which is strongly encouraged by the Ubuntu community.  The `#` prompt would be showed if the user was at a `root` logon.  The prompt would also be different if you were in an app such as the `mysql>` prompt for a terminal mysql session.)*

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

While you are at it, since this is a fresh install you should update libraries and packages with:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
$ sudo update-grub
```

The GRUB update will add all the detected Operation systems to the Grub Menu.  It may not detect the Windows 10 installation if it's in a hibernation state.

To remove Windows 10 from Hibernation, run a Windows 10 repair program.

### Install Windows Boot Manager

From the Windows Installation disk, click **Repair your computer** on the second screen -> (click) **Troubleshoot** -> **Advance options** -> **Command Prompt** -> Run these commands one after the other:

```
x:\Sources>bootrec /RebuildBcd
x:\Sources>bootrec /fixMbr
x:\Sources>bootrec /fixboot
x:\Sources>exit
```

*(the `x:\Sources>` is the command prompt.  Type in the commands after the prompt and press enter.  Run each of them in the order presented.)*

**Click on the option to `Turn Off PC`.**  Then Reboot into Windows.  While in Windows Disable the Hibernation.

After this repair, it may overwrite your Grub installation.  You can fix this by following the steps provided at:
[Installing Windows 10 on partition removed Ubuntu option for UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/a/877815/29012)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55739/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-downloaded-ubuntu-for-dual-boot-with-windows).

Comment: When I try to start repair it doesn't do it, it says Start up repair couldn't repair your PC, Press advanced options to try other options to repair your PC or shut down to turn off. Anything else I can try ? :(